# FormGroup.valueChanges fires on 'change' & 'blur' only when the field type is "number"

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feu1az

If I change the value of Text 1 or Text 2 the event is firing once. But when I change the value of the last field, which is of type number, then it is firing on change and blur and this causes some problems in my webapp.

**Question:**

Why is the "valueChange" event triggering on 'change' and 'blur' when the field type is "number"?

How I can prevent this?

(Same behavior on Chrome/Firefox/EDGE)

Comment: Not the answer but it seems to be related to those steppers of the number field. Interestingly, using those steppers (in chrome on the right) instead of typing the number you don't get the valueChange onBlur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12540

The reason is that Angular listens for both events - `input` and `change` - for `input[type=number]` control. I think that was intended because browsers can  handle those events differently.

You can either use a small workaround:

```
<input [type]="'number'"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k2gusz?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

or use [distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12540#issuecomment-500061861) to prevent unnecessary calls.